# ASP.NET Filter IQueryable with Custom Expression

Tags: c#, linq

I'm currently working on an ASP.NET application in .NET 4.5. Currently I'm retrieving 2 View results from my database using an `IQueryable`:

1. MainProject
2. SubProject

`MainProject`s and `SubProject`s have different properties, but do have 1 property in common, an `ObjectNumber`, which I defined in an interface `ISearchResult`.

I would like to write an Expression to filter both View results with only 1 method, instead of writing the same coding twice.

My View result classes and the interface look like this:

```
public interface ISarchResult
{
    int ID { get; set; }
    string ObjectNr { get; set; }
}

public class MainProject : ISearchResult
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public DateTime? CreationDate { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string ObjectNr { get; set; }
}

public class SubProject : ISuchResultat
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string ObjectNr { get; set; }
    public short State { get; set; }
    public int? Anything { get; set; }
    public int? Something { get; set; }
}
```

In my Code Behind class I have my filter method, which looks like this:

```
private IQueryable<MainProject> FilterObjectNumbers(IQueryable<MainProject > result)
{
    var objectNumbers = this.objectNrField.Text.Split(',').Select(objNr => objNr.Trim()).Where(t => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(t)).ToList();

    if (objectNumbers.Count > 0)
    {
        var projectIDs = objectNumbers.Select(objNr => Util.StringToInt(objNr)).Where(objNr => objNr > 0).ToList();
        result = result.Where(i => objectNumbers.Contains(i.ObjectNr) || projectIDs.Contains(i.PK_ID));
    }      

    return result;
}
```

Do you know how to transform this Method into a query Expression, to filter my `IQueryable` for type `MainProject` as well as type `SubProject`?

Is it possible to put this Expression Filter method into an extension method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a generic extension method with a `ISarchResult` constraint

```
public static IQueryable<T> FilterObjectNumbers<T>(this IQueryable<T> result, string objectNrFieldText)
    where T : ISarchResult {
    var objectNumbers = objectNrFieldText.Split(',').Select(objNr => objNr.Trim()).Where(t => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(t)).ToList();

    if (objectNumbers.Count > 0) {
        var projectIDs = objectNumbers.Select(objNr => Util.StringToInt(objNr)).Where(objNr => objNr > 0).ToList();
        result = result.Where(i => objectNumbers.Contains(i.ObjectNr) || projectIDs.Contains(i.ID));
    }      

    return result;
}
```

It can then be used

```
//assuming IQueriable<MainProject> mainProjectResult
var filteredResult = mainProjectResult.FilterObjectNumbers(this.objectNrField.Text);
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you, exactly what I was searching for :))